# A detail in the proof of the Theorem of the Uniqueness of the Laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

So the theorem is as follows

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in the ring $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,r_1<|z-z_0|<r_2\}$. Also assume that
> $$
>   f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\,\,\forall z\in A,
> $$
> where both series converge independently. Then
> $$
>   a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z_0)^{n+1}}dw\quad\text{and}\quad b_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma}f(w)(w-z_0)^{n-1}dw
> $$
> where $\gamma(\theta)=z_0+r\,e^{i\,\theta}$ with $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ and $r_1<r<r_2$.

The proof begins quoting Abel's Lemma to assure that both series converge uniformly in $\gamma$, and so
$$
\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{k+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^{n-(k+1)}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^{n+(k+1)}}
$$
too converge uniformly on $\gamma$, this allows us to interchange the sum and the integral. So far so good, however the next step is where I am having trouble following along, it states that:

> if $k\geq0$, integrating term by term, we get
> $$
>   \int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{k+1}}dz=2\pi\,i\,a_k.
> $$
> And if $k<0$, we get
> $$
>   \int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{k+1}}dz=2\pi\,i\,b_{-k}.
> $$

It's clear to me that Cauchy's Theorem is used; first, if $k\geq0$, then in
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{\gamma}\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^{n+(k+1)}}dz
$$
$\gamma$ is never homotopic to a point, and so the integral is never zero, on the other hand
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{\gamma}a_n(z-z_0)^{n-(k+1)}dz
$$
will be zero as soon as $n-(k+1)\geq0$ which is when $n\geq k+1$ and so we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{k} \int_{\gamma}a_n(z-z_0)^{n-(k+1)}dz.
$$
Am I missing something? I know this is a lot to take in, if I am not clear enough please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

No, only for a net exponent of $-1$ do you get nonzero integrals. Otherwise, the integral is $0$ — even with negative exponents — by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. It’s not about Cauchy’s Theorem.